# Execute any sql through one JdbcTemplate method?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

I want to offer an internal endpoint where users can input *any* sql (select, deletes, updates, subselects). And send it to a database using `NamedQueryJdbcTemplate`.

Eg: 
`jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, callbackHandler);`

Problem: if the select does not return any value, the method above will fail with `java.sql.SQLException: The executeQuery method must return a result set.`.

For non-selects, the `jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params)` would have to be called.

But for my goal, I'd then have to do a lexical parsing of the sql, and determine if the query is actually a `SELECT` or not. At least for subselects like `DELETE FROM table where id IN (SELECT id from....))` that would already be a problem.

So: how can I execute **any** sql through a single `JdbcTemplate` method. And *if* there is a return value, just return it. Otherwise ignore the return?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea.  The Spring JDBC template has undergone extensive refactoring and improvement since 2003.  Your idea seems like a wrong headed attempt to take it an unnecessary step further.  I would advise against it.

Comment: Querying and updating data are fundamentally different.  There's no unification there.